# 301 Redirect and query strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string, http-status-code-301

I am looking to create a 301 redirect based purely on a query string see b

```
OLD URL: olddomain.com/?pc=/product/9999
New URL: newurl.php?var=yup
```

My normal way of doing this would be

```
redirect 301 pc=/product/9999 newurl.php?var=yup
```

But this time I am trying to match a URL that that only contains the domain and a query string...

What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a bit more explanation? I don't see any correlation between your first URL and the second. How is "var=yup" tied to "/product/9999"?

Comment: In the scenario I am dealing with there isn't... We are about to lauch a New website, so all links are completely different. The Old site only used query strings for all pages

Comment: Okay, so you're simply trying to redirect all old traffic to a single page on the new site no matter what the old URL is?

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using the a rewrite rule (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following to solve my problems:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pc=/product/9999
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/index.php?var=yup [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to solve my problems

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^art_id=33128 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/pages/33128?  [R=301,L]
```

To remove unwanted query string after rewriting, use '?' after Rewrite Rule